# What range of RGB is considered "blue"?

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

I'm getting image pixel data like this:

```
var p = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
var red = p[0];
var green = p[1];
var blue p[2];
```

Sorry for this but my question is not much about code, what range of rgb is considered to be blue color? (for example red color may consist of blue color too, but we call it red, how to determine it?)

Comment: I don't think there is a fixed definition. I'd open a colour palette and try to define it for myself.

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks, I thought there would be someone ho already did it for me :)

Comment: @karaxuna you can are looking for blue color space. 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=blue&a=*C.blue-_*ColorSet-&a=*DPClash.ColorE.blue-_**Mathematica.Blue-.dflt-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any colour in the hue range from 180 to 300 can be considered blue, since that's the primary colour that is dominant. However, if you want to consider secondary colours too, then your range is 210 to 270. Then you have to factor in things like "it still looks cyan" (since green is far more perceptually bright than blue) and stuff like that, there's really no hard-and-fast definition.

So what you could do is say "if( max( red, green, blue) == blue) then it's blue" and nobody can fault you for it.

Comment: I like "if( max( red, green, blue) == blue) then it's blue" idea, it's simple :)